# How to set attributes piecemeal in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have a model, say Question, with fields time_asked and time_answered. I want to be able to set time_asked when the question is served, and time_answered when a response is posted. Is this possible and how might I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [active record callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) to do so.
Suppose you have a separate class `Response` and it belongs to `Question`.
So your code for time_asked will look like:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :responses
  before_create :fill_time_asked

  private
  def fill_time_asked
    time_asked = Time.now
  end
end
```

`response.rb`:

```
class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  before_create :fill_time_answered

  private
  def fill_time_answered
    question.time_aswered = Time.now
  end
end
```

Another way to do it is to manually call proper methods, e.g. `question.asked!` or `question.answered!` from your controllers. However, the rails way is to keep business logic in your models and have thin controllers.